# Converting timestamp in hive

Tags: hive

I have a timestamp value like "`Nov 27, 2016 8:30:00 AM`" which I want to convert TIMESTAMP(6) format i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff`

Can anyone suggest how easily can this be achieved in hiveQL.

Comment: which hive version ur using?

Comment: 1.2.1 to be precise Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-258

Answer (score 1):

Use the unix_timsestamp function to get the date

```
    hive> Select unix_timestamp("NOV 27, 2017", "MMM DD, YYYY") from xyz;
    OK
    1483257600
    Time taken: 0.082 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
    hive> Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("NOV 27,2016 8:30:00 AM", "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss aa")) from xyz;
    OK
    2016-11-27 08:30:00
    Time taken: 0.075 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Other options for unix_timestamp can be found [here](https://www.qubole.com/resources/cheatsheet/hive-function-cheat-sheet/)